# Python script with multiple rest queries fails when run in a docker container

Tags: python, json, rest, docker, marathon

I have a python script which uses flask_restful and have queries different services via REST 3 times with in a script and all the 3 REST queries are sequential and there is a data dependency. We use the JSON response object of the first rest query to build the json request for the next one. The python script works perfectly fine when run in my local machine and when moved to the docker container and run. The script fails with an error saying "No JSON object could be decoded" from the response object of the first JSON query.

```
from flask_restful import Api, request
import json
import requests

resp = requests.post(url=url,data=dat,headers=headers)
json_data = json.loads(resp.content)
```

resp.content throws

```
raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

But the same script works when run locally. Thank you. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: This means you have "forgottent" to add some component, Python library or anything in your Dockerfile

Comment: Does the response have any information at all? Try looking at the content without `json.loads` there may be a useful error message there. I would also review the container's network configuration and confirm it's properly networked such that it can reach the required resources.

Comment: @user2915097: I included flask and requests but did not include json. Does json library come as a built in with python?

Comment: Yes json is included, and you do not have a `ImportError...` after the line `import json`

Comment: @user2915097: So I hope the dependencies are right. I am not using any other library other than the mentioned

Comment: I tested the docker image locally and the script works just fine even with the docker but fails when run this image in marathon, a container orchestration platform

Comment: There was so access issue within the network. Thank you for the comments ***Resolved***